# Set programmaticaly the Text property calling a function from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to initialise the label of the button from function from code behind:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnAjoutClient" runat="server" Text='<%= GetText()%>' />
```

and in the code behing a simple function like:

```
protected String GetText() {
  return "test";
}
```

But the caption of the button shows me the raw code (and the function is never called). I tryied also `<%# GetText() %>`. Do you know why ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `<%=%>` server side code block like that within a server side control.

Use the code behind file:

```
BtnAjoutClient.Text = GetText();
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you really want to do this, it can be done using `Expression Builders` - we use this general [Code Expression Builder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx) all over the place.

Allows you do do

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnAjoutClient" runat="server" Text='<%$ Code :  GetText()%>' />
```

This essentialy changes the code at compile-time into.

```
BtnAjoutClient.Text = GetText();
```